# Изменение настроек Grails

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

Совсем небольшая проблемка - при запуске первого проекта на Grails(2.4.4) с Tomcat(7), Томкат выдает ошибку. И предполагается, что проблема в том, что Grails пытается создать в папке с Томкатом файлы типа stacktrace.log и h2 database и у него не хватает прав. 
Как сменить настройки так, чтобы файлы писались в директорию, которая доступна для записи? Или как сделать так, чтобы файлы нормально создавались в папке с Томкатом?

Answer (score 0):

Помогите развернуть Grails на Tomcat.
Я с помощью idea создал простое grails приложение, добавил один контроллер и сделал war с помощью команды -grails war.

Запустил Tomcat 9 (только скачал, кроме юзер.xml ничего в нём не изменял). 
Обычной тестовый war с java сервлетом "Hello world" отработал как надо, вернул "Hello world" на index.jsp. При работе с Grails .war, Tomcat нормально открывает первую страницу, где указаны контроллеры.
При нажатии на контроллер, открывает следующую страницу, но выдаёт ошибку "An error has occurred". В чём проблема? 
Пробовал на локальном сервере.

P.S. в tomcat никаких библиотек для grails не добавлял. 
Как правильно развертывать grails war на tomcat?[image: Первая страница grails]

[image: После нажатия на контроллер]